# why wont my program paintComponent() if I set an ImageIcon and Image?

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, paintcomponent

I've tried to find similar questions, but I think I have a unique situation here.

I am programming a game in java, my main class creates a frame which adds a component class which is an extension of JPanel. Basically, I draw these ovals and they move around and do different things, and I want to implement a method inside of one my classes which will use an image instead of an oval. However, anytime I try to create and image from a file, the program will not run the overridden "paintComponent(Graphics g)" method.

My main:

```
package mikeengine;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MikeEngine {

static final int fx = 1300;
static final int fy = 800;
static final int px = 1292;
static final int py = 767;

static interactivePanel levelPanel;

public static void pause() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10); // wait 10ms
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MEngine");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(fx, fy);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    levelPanel = new interactivePanel();
    addship();
    frame.getContentPane().add(levelPanel);
    levelPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
    while (true) {
        pause();
        levelPanel.move();
        levelPanel.repaint();
    }
}

static void addship() {
    PlayerShip ship = new PlayerShip(100, 25, 25, px, 0, py, 0);
    ship.setGraphic("C:/Users/asdf/Documents/NetBeansProjects/mikeEngine/src/mikeengine/res/right-arrow.jpg");
    levelPanel.addObject(ship);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        PlayerShip ship2 = new PlayerShip((int) (Math.random() * 1000) + 100, (int) (Math.random() * 1000) + 100, 25, px, px / 2, py, 0);
        ship2.setMovement((int) (Math.random() * 10) / 5, (int) (Math.random() * 10) / 2);
        levelPanel.addObject(ship2);
    }
}

}
```

now, if I comment out the line:

`ship.setGraphic("C:/Users/asdf/Documents/NetBeansProjects/mikeEngine/src/mikeengine/res/right-arrow.jpg");`

everything renders perfectly.
I don't even paint the image that is going to be created. The image variable is just part of a class and it is currently just being created and doing nothing, so I don't understand how it affects the paintcomponentMethod(), if the paintComponent() isn't even told to try to paint the image ever.

The "PlayerShip" class extends the abstract "OnScreenObject" class (you really shouldn't need to see the code for PlayerShip, it only overrides one irrelevant method).

OnScreenObject looks like so:

```
package mikeengine;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public abstract class OnScreenObject {

private ImageIcon graphic;
Image g;
protected int xmin;
protected int ymin;
protected int xsize;
protected int ysize;
protected int rise;
protected int run;
protected int containerYMax;
protected int containerYMin;
protected int containerXMax;
protected int containerXMin;

protected boolean visible;
protected boolean allowedOffscreen;
protected boolean isSelected;

protected Color color;

OnScreenObject(int x, int y, int sizeX, int sizeY, int cxMax, int cxMin, int cyMax, int cyMin) {
    xmin = x;
    ymin = y;
    xsize = sizeX;
    ysize = sizeY;
    containerXMax = cxMax;
    containerXMin = cxMin;
    containerYMax = cyMax;
    containerYMin = cyMin;

    //
    rise = 0;
    run = 0;

    visible = true;
    allowedOffscreen = false;
    isSelected = false;
}

public int getXMin() {
    return xmin;
}

public int getYMin() {
    return ymin;
}

public int getXMax() {
    return xmin + xsize;
}

public int getYMax() {
    return ymin + ysize;
}

public int getXSize() {
    return xsize;
}

public int getYSize() {
    return ysize;
}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public boolean getAllowedOffscreen() {
    return allowedOffscreen;
}

public boolean getVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public int getRun() {
    return run;
}

public ImageIcon getGraphic() {
    return graphic;
}

public boolean isWithin(int x, int y) {
    return x >= xmin && x <= getXMax() && y >= ymin && y <= getYMax();
}

public void setXMin(int x) {
    xmin = x;
}

public void setYMin(int y) {
    ymin = y;
}

public void setXSize(int x) {
    xsize = x;
}

public void setYSize(int y) {
    ysize = y;
}

public void setGraphic(String setto) {
    try{
    graphic = new ImageIcon("setto");
    g=graphic.getImage();
        System.out.println("tried");
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("caught:" + e);
    }

}

public void setAllowedOffscreen(boolean allowed) {
    allowedOffscreen = allowed;
}

public void setMovement(int riseM, int runM) {
    rise = riseM * -1;//rise means to go up, and negative will move it up
    run = runM;
}

public void nudge(boolean horizontal, int amount) {
    if (horizontal) {
        run += amount;
    } else {
        rise += amount;
    }
}

public void setVisible(boolean vis) {
    visible = vis;
}

public void setColor(Color c) {
    color = c;
}

public boolean checkCollide(OnScreenObject other) {
    if (other.getYMax() < getYMin()) { //if other object is above this
        return false;
    }
    if (other.getYMin() > getYMax()) {//if other object is below this
        return false;
    }
    if (other.getXMax() < getXMin()) {//if other is to the left
        return false;
    }
    if (other.getXMin() > getXMax()) {//if other is to the right
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void move() {
    if (!allowedOffscreen) {
        checkEdge();
    }
    xmin += run;
    ymin += rise;
}

protected abstract void checkEdge();

}
```

The interactivePanel class is the one that extends JPanel:

```
package mikeengine;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class interactivePanel extends JPanel {

ArrayList<OnScreenObject> objects;
IClick myClick;
Ipress myType;
PlayerShip currentShip;

interactivePanel() {
    objects = new ArrayList<>();
    myClick = new IClick();
    myType = new Ipress();
    this.addMouseListener(myClick);
    this.addKeyListener(myType);

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("painting");
    paintBackground(g);
    paintObjects(g);
    checkClick();
    checkPress();
}

public void move() {
    System.out.println("here2");
    checkDeadShip();//also sets current ship
    moveObjects();//also removes invisible
    checkCollisions();

} // end method move

private void checkClick() {
    if (!myClick.getClicked()) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        OnScreenObject current = objects.get(i);
        if (current.isWithin(myClick.getX(), myClick.getY())) {
            System.out.println("CLICKED");
        }
    }
}

private void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}

private void paintObjects(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        OnScreenObject current = objects.get(i);
        g.setColor(current.getColor());
        g.fillOval(current.getXMin(), current.getYMin(), current.getXSize(), current.getYSize());
    }
}

public void addObject(OnScreenObject toAdd) {
    objects.add(toAdd);
}

private void checkPress() {
    if (myType.getDown()) {
        objects.get(0).nudge(false, 3);
    }
    if (myType.getUp()) {
        objects.get(0).nudge(false, -3);
    }
    if (myType.getLeft()) {
        objects.get(0).nudge(true, -3);
    }
    if (myType.getRight()) {
        objects.get(0).nudge(true, 3);
    }
    if (myType.getSpace()) {
        fire();
    }
}

private void fire() {
    OnScreenObject shotBullet = new Bullet(currentShip.getXMax(), ((currentShip.getYMax() - currentShip.getYMin()) / 2) + currentShip.getYMin(), 5, getWidth(), 0, getHeight(), 0);
    int shipBonus = 0;
    if (currentShip.getRun() > 0) {
        shipBonus = currentShip.getRun();
    }
    shotBullet.setMovement(0, shipBonus + 5);
    addObject(shotBullet);
}

private void checkCollisions() {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < objects.size(); j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                OnScreenObject current = objects.get(i);
                OnScreenObject next = objects.get(j);
                if (current.checkCollide(next)) {
                    objects.remove(i);
                    if (i < j) {
                        objects.remove(j - 1);
                    } else {
                        objects.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void checkDeadShip() {
    if (objects.size() > 0) {
        try {
            currentShip = (PlayerShip) objects.get(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("GAME OVER!");
        }
    }
}

private void moveObjects() {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        OnScreenObject current = objects.get(i);
        current.move();
        if (!current.getVisible()) {
            objects.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
}
```

if I do not have that line commented out, the

`System.out.println("painting");` inside of my `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` is never run, which is why I assume that paintComponent isn't running. 
(I cant post images since I don't have 10 rep, but its just a JFrame with the beige empty panel look when it is not commented out).

Comment: Instead of dropping all your code you should post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: `"you really shouldn't need to see the code for PlayerShip, it only overrides one irrelevant method..."` -- until you know the source of your problem, no assumptions should be made. And yeah, I agree with @Pshemo: you will want to do some work to try to isolate the problem by creating a new program that borrows from your current code, but only has enough code to compile, run and show us your problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Pshemo
I didn't dump all my code, I omitted like 6 classes.
I don't understand what in these classes is causing the program, so I wouldn't know which parts to omit.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels
Playership only overrides the CheckEdge() method, which has nothing to do with visuals. It just changes the behavior of the object when it hits the border by setting the object's rise and run to different numbers.

Comment: The likely hood is your are blocking the EDT

Comment: Add a border to the level panel to make sure it's being laid out correctly...

Comment: @MadProgrammer
I tried to add the border inside the constructor of the interactivePanel class, and that didn't fix it, so instead I tried to add the border inside the main method, and that changed nothing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

In your setGraphic() method, replace the line

```
graphic = new ImageIcon("setto");
```

with this:

```
graphic = new ImageIcon(this.getClass()
                .getResource(setto));
```

Comment: While good advice, If paintCompment is never being called, it's not likely to help .... Immediately

Comment: Brilliant. Glad to hear it. +1 for your gratitude.

Comment: (unfortunately I cant upvote your solution, so you'll have to accept a check instead).

Comment: That'll do nicely. Thanks.

Comment: It would be interesting to find out whether just graphic = new ImageIcon(setto); (as opposed to graphic = new ImageIcon("setto");) works too, but don't worry if you can't be bothered. Have a +1 for your question too, because I've learnt something myself

Comment: I misquoted my code when I originally posted it, and it did not have the quotes around the setto. (I had changed from parameter to absolute path and back, and forgot to remove the quotes).

It did not work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. +1 for info.

Comment: lol. Thanks. Confession: it might not have been a guess: I got it from another answer to what turned out to be the same question. +1 for amusing comment. I believe in the maxim 'nothing ventured, nothing gained'. A former lecturer of mine said he could always tell when he was marking my paper, because my approcah was experimental. I believe trial and improvement. Experimentation is a fundamental part of the scientific method and human learning in general. Bold to state it as an answer without having tested it myself, but I thought the prize of the satisfaction of helping someone and solving a

Comment: problem were worth the potential risk of getting a bit of egg on my face. A possible danger with this approach is if you can be banned from answering questions if you delete too many answers as you can with asking questions if you delete too many (my guess is that you can't be).